# Moving Paddle with mouse (Arkanoid)

Tags: processing

I am having a slight problem. I'm creating a basic Arkanoid using processing but I can't figure out how to make the paddle move with my mouse. I have it currently set up to move on a click for this example.

```java
void setup() {

size(400, 400);
rectMode(CENTER);
ellipseMode(CENTER);
}

void draw() {
  background(#EFF8FB);

  batMain();
  ballMain();
}

float ballX = 200, ballY = 200;
float direction = PI * .3f;
byte  speed = 4;

final static byte  ballSize  = 20;
final static color ballColor = #2EFE2E;

void ballMain() {
  // Draw the ball
  fill(ballColor);
  ellipse(ballX, ballY, ballSize, ballSize);


  ballX += speed * cos(direction);
  ballY += speed * sin(direction);
  walls();

  if (direction > TWO_PI)        direction -= TWO_PI;
  else if (direction < -TWO_PI)  direction += TWO_PI;
}

short a = 200;

final static color batColor = #5858FA;

void batMain() {
  // Draw the bat
  fill(batColor);
  rect(a, 380, 60, 10);
  noStroke();

  if (mousePressed) {

    // Right side of the screen
    if (mouseX > width>>1)    a += 4;
    // Other side of the screen
    else                      a -= 4;
  }


  if (ballY + 10 > 375 && ballY + 10 < 385 && ballX + 10 > a - 30 && ballX -   10    < a + 30) {

    if (ballX + 10 > a - 30 && ballX < a - 15) { // Left part
      direction = TWO_PI - direction;
      ++speed;
    }

    else if (ballX - 10 < a + 30 && ballX < a + 15) {
      direction = TWO_PI - direction;
      ++speed;
    } 
     else {
      direction = TWO_PI - direction;
      speed = 4;
    }
  }
}

void walls() {

   if (ballX < 10) {
    ballX = 11;
    direction = PI - direction;
  }
  if (ballX > 390) {
    ballX = 389;
    direction = PI - direction;
  }
  if (ballY < 10) {
    ballY = 11;
    direction = TWO_PI - direction;
  }
  if (ballY > 390) {
    ballY = 389;
    direction = TWO_PI - direction;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you not code a mouseMoved function that gets passed a mouseEvent, which should contain getX and getY properties showing how far the mouse has moved. Simply alter your paddle'c current X position by the getX value from the mouseEvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the logic here:

```java
if (mousePressed) {

    // Right side of the screen
    if (mouseX > width>>1)    a += 4;
    // Other side of the screen
    else                      a -= 4;
  }
```

If you want the paddle to follow the mouse even when you aren't pressing it, just get rid of that outer if statement:

```java
    // Right side of the screen
    if (mouseX > width>>1){    
       a += 4;
    }
    // Other side of the screen
    else{
       a -= 4;
    }
```

Or if you want the paddle to be at the mouse's position, just use that directly:

```java
a = mouseX;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I try the first statement you posted and that worked fine. However, I tried the 

    a = mouseX

and I'm getting errors

Comment: @GregoryHartley That's probably because your `a` variable is a `short` and `mouseX` is an `int`. Just make `a` an `int` or a `float`.

Comment: Seemed to work but only on the right side of the screen. The paddle stops half way when I moved the mouse to the left side

Comment: I have solved it. I deleted the Else statement. Thank you